# How to send and access a parameter/value upon Form Submission to next controller

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am  new to Laravel.
I have a controller method which retrieves data from request, creates a model instance
and saves it to database.

It then redirects to controller with a value (user name)

```
 return redirect()->action('SignupController@confirm' , $username);
```

Route for confirm is :

```
Route::get('confirm/{user}' , 'SignupController@confirm');
```

In 'confirm' method i retrieved value from variable and passed it to view

```
public function confirm($username)
    {
        return view('auth.confirm')->with('username' , $username);
    }
```

Confirm view present a form to confirm account and upon succesful submission post to route :

```
Route::post('confirm' , 'SignupController@confirmCode');
```

In 'confirmCode' i want to access that value which i actully fetched from user input
and passed down the line.
But i am unable to do it , i even tried post route with a wild card

```
Route::post('confirm/{user}' , 'SignupController@confirmCode');
```

and tried to access it similarly as before , but it is not passed along when form submits as i get nothing when i 
tried to look for it using var_dump($username).

Error is :

```
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\SignupController::confirmCode()
```

By the way, temporarily i am using hidden field to do the job which is not a good idea obviously. 
I know i am missing something. Looking forward for some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't my answer worked for you ?

Comment: Thank You , definitely i am going to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [Session::flash](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#flash-data) or if it's more than one redirect then you can use Session::put.

```
use Session; // at the top between class and namespace

public function confirm($username)
{
  Session::flash('username', $username);
  // Session::put('username',$username);
  return view('auth.confirm')->with('username' , $username);
}

public function confirmCode() {
    dd(Session::get('username'));
}
```